# How to access WorkbookCreated object with Excel JavaScript Add-In?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

The Excel JS Add-In Api docs ([Excel.WorkbookCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbookcreated?view=excel-js-preview)) say:

```
The WorkbookCreated object is the top level object created by Application.CreateWorkbook.
A WorkbookCreated object is a special Workbook object.
```

This leads me to believe that a WorkbookCreated object is used to access a newly created workbook, but there is no explanation or examples about accessing the WorkbookCreated object after creating a new workbook.

I was able to successfully create a new workbook with the following code:

```
// dbg() is a function to output text to the html window within the excel plugin.

function makeWorkbook() {
    Excel.run(async context => {
        Excel.createWorkbook().then(() => {
            dbg('created');
        });
        return context.sync().then(() => {
            dbg('sync completed');
        });
    });
}
```

I can only access the newly created workbook after this function is run, the new workbook is manually selected by the user and then another command is run.

Is there a way to access the newly created workbook within the makeWorkbook() function above without user intervention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that our system for generating API reference documentation puts the `createWorkbook` method near the end of a very long page. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=excel-js-preview#excel-createworkbook-base64-) will jump you right to it. It appears from the example there that you need to use the JavaScript FileReader object.

UPDATE: There is more official documentation at [Create a workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook). A key sentence is "When this method is called, the new workbook is immediately opened and displayed in a new instance of Excel. Your add-in remains open and running with the previous workbook."

An add-in basically lives in a sandboxed JavaScript engine that is embedded in the particular instance of Excel in which the add-in is opened. The add-in cannot reach out to another instance of Excel, just as it can't reach out to any other process on your computer for security reasons. So, there is no way to access the newly created workbook from within the add-in that created it with `Excel.createWorkbook`.

Comment: I've already managed to create a new workbook using the createWorkbook method (as shown in my original post).  What I need to understand is how to work with that newly created workbook.

Comment: That's what I thought, but what is the use of a WorkbookCreated object?